# Creating foreground background array in QT

Tags: c++, arrays, image, qt

I'm having a problem with creating an array that gives me the information about 2 images that are drawn upon each other.

What I have is 1 image as background (the sea) and 1 image as foreground (landscape) the landscape is not so big as the sea, so when drawn upon each other you can see the sea as well as the landscape on it.

Now I want to make an array that sets me an 0 if it is the sea and a 1 if it is the landscape. So I could use
this array to do some collision detection later. The problem is I don't find how to make a bytearray from it. 
off length * width of the images.

I have both images in an QImage, but I don't find how to create the array with a for loop or something.

Both images are drawn upon each other with the QPainter function.

Can someone help me?

Kind regards,

Comment: Use QGraphicsView. It has built-in collision detection and will be easier for you to implement it.

Comment: I know about the built in collision detection but I can't use that for my project. It is a school project, and we must implement our own collision detection. That's why I need an array of 1 and 0. Thnx for you help btw.

Answer (score 0):

If you draw the two images upon each other with the QPainter class, you loose any information about them, they are *just* drawings now. you must create methods and objects to implement your school project. I know that you can't use the QGraphicsView, but what you need is to **look** how qgraphicsview works so you will have a bit of information on how to implement your own collision system.

1 - you need to keep the Retangle of your drawings ( all of them ) saved somewhere. a QList will do.

2 - you need the Positions of your Drawings too, so y ou know where they are, besides the retangles.

with the positions, and the rectangles, all you need to do is check if one rectangle intersects another.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with 2 forloops and used black and blue to determine the fore and background. So I can only use black and blue.